# Load jQuery calls/plugins before page appears to user

Tags: jquery, html, preload

I noticed on my website that all jQuery functions and plugins I use start loading after the main webpage is loaded. This is no big problem, but the thing is I use jQuery to style my `<forms>` elements and hide error messages, so when user accesses a page for about 1 second they see ugly form and all messages and than jQuery loads it looks fine.

I included my jQuery plugin calls and functions before the `</head>` tag and wrapped them into

```
$(document).ready(function() { //My Code Here });
```

**Code example:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    //Form stylin
    $('form').call_form_styling('form' , { labels: true, });

    //Hide error div's with class = "error"
    $('.error').hide();  

});

</script>
<head>
<body>
<form>
<!-- Suff like inputs here -->
<div class="error">error</div>
<form>
<! -- other code bla bla -->
</body>
```

---

So could you please suggest any solutions to load jQuery functions and plugins before page is shown to a user, so they don't see ugly stuff.

Comment: `$(document).ready` loads after the closing </body> tag is read. There are likely better solutions, but you could always call the jquery script directly after you've written the elements, and don't use `ready` to make it fire right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a read of what jQuery's [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) does, you'll see that it simple sets the element's display state to none. Therefore, one way around this issue would be to set some inline styles for your elements that you want to hide on page load, that way you can then use jQuery to fade them in again, eg:

`<div class="error">error</div>` becomes `<div class="error" style="display: none;">error</div>`

Comment: That's a solution for one problem, do you have any suggestions about form_styling? what it does it applies some rules css/javascript rules to a form to style things like chckboxes and inputs.

Comment: I'd use a class for your form and inputs, only apply that class once the form has been submitted.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest hiding your form until it has been styled, then show it. Or just style it with CSS like a normal person ;)

Comment: Yeh like a real person ;D , the prob is that a big part of it is also a jQuery functionality, e.g. fade in placeholders, slides etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest loading the css first and perhaps add display none to your form.

```
<form style="display:none;">
    <div class="error">error</div>
</form>
```

Place your JS after the end body tag. Once jQuery is loaded, you can change the class or add events to your form.